# Custom redirections to make the cart page inaccessible in WooCommerce

Tags: php, wordpress, redirect, woocommerce, cart

I would like the WooCommerce cart page to be inaccessible.

- If a user is trying to reach the cart page when the cart is empty, redirect to the homepage.
- If a user is trying to reach the cart page when the cart is not empty, redirect to checkout.

Is that possible?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use this very simple code, so when customer try to reach cart page it is redirected to:

- home page when cart is empty
- checkout page if cart is not empty

The code snippet:

```
add_action('template_redirect', 'custom_cart_redirections');
function custom_cart_redirections() {
    if ( is_cart() ) {
        if ( WC()->cart->is_empty() ) {
            wp_redirect( home_url('/') );
            exit();
        } else {
            wp_redirect( wc_get_checkout_url() );
            exit();
        }
    }
}
```

Code goes in functions.php file of the active child theme (or active theme). Tested and works.